# humane-test-output doesn't seem to work with ClojureScript's lein doo command

Tags: clojurescript

I've had a heck of a time getting `lein doo node test` to work with `humane-test-output`.

Modifying my `~/.lein/profiles.clj` as suggested in the readme doesn't work.

I just keep getting the same (relatively unfriendly) default output from ClojureScript's failing tests.

What is the minimum configuration required in order to get `lein doo` and `humane-test-output` working together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two steps got this working for me:

First: In my `project.clj`, I added this line:

`:profiles {:dev {:dependencies [[pjstadig/humane-test-output "0.8.2"]]}}`

Second: my test runner `cljs` file looks like this:

```
(ns cljs-router.runner
  (:require [doo.runner :refer-macros [doo-tests]]
            [pjstadig.humane-test-output] ; This is the key right here
            [cljs-router.core-test]))

(doo-tests 'cljs-router.core-test)
```

After that, I got nice, humane test output for my failing tests.